# Error 'No converter found capable of converting from type XXX' when using @Query("Select * from")

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, jpql

I have a class `DocumentData`:

```
@Data //Lombok
public class DocumentData {

    private Long documentId;
    private Long binderId;
    private String containerCode;
    private String barcode;
    private Long clientId;

}
```

I have my Repository:

```
public interface DocumentArchiveRepository extends JpaRepository<DocumentArchive, Long> {

    String QUERY_GET_DOCUMENT_DATA = "SELECT DISTINCT d.id_document, pd.id_binder, s.container_code, d.barcode, k.id_client FROM table1 pd \n"
            + "JOIN table2 d ON pd.id_document = d.id_cokument\n"
            + "JOIN table3 s ON s.id = pd.id_binder \n"
            + "JOIN table4 k ON k.id_document = d.id_document\n"
            + "WHERE pd.id_position = 10122 AND d.id_document in :documentIds";

    @Query(value = QUERY_GET_DOCUMENT_DATA, nativeQuery = true)
    List<DocumentData> getDocumentData(@Param("documentIds") List<Long> documentIds);
```

When I want to get data:

```
List<DocumentData> documentData = repository.getDocumentData(documentIds);
```

I get the following error:

> org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No
>   converter found capable of converting from type
>   [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap]
>   to type [pl.ultimo.retention.archive.dto.DocumentData]    at
>   org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:321)
>   ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:194)
>   ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:174)
>   ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]

Should I change my code to `List<Object>` and the anually map results to `DocumentData`? Or maybe there is a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to wrap the query in constructor:

```
String QUERY_GET_DOCUMENT_DATA = "SELECT new " + DocumentData.class.getName() + "(d.id_document, pd.id_binder, s.container_code, d.barcode, k.id_client) FROM table1 pd "
        + "JOIN table2 d ON pd.id_document = d.id_cokument "
        + "JOIN table3 s ON s.id = pd.id_binder "
        + "JOIN table4 k ON k.id_document = d.id_document "
        + "WHERE pd.id_position = 10122 AND d.id_document in :documentIds";
```

Notice braces. Also I'm using `DocumentData.class.getName()`, but simply using name `"DocumentData"` works, if it's unique on classpath. I'm not sure if this can be run as native query, try it out, if not - run as jpql.

Other solution would be to define custom `Converter` implementation and annotate the wuery with `@Converter`.

Comment: Your first solution doesnt work, I get the error: ERROR: syntax error at or near "."

Comment: The second solution with JPQL - should I add entities like Table1, Table2, Table3 and Table4? I dont have these entities currently

Comment: jpql is not the second solution, I have written, that running this query won't work as native sql, this dot, that it is complaining about is probably from package name of `DocumentData` class

Comment: You're right so String QUERY_GET_DOCUMENT_DATA = "SELECT new com.mypackage.dto.DocumentData(d.id_document, d. ... doesn't work

Comment: did you run it as jpql? using `Hibernate#createQuery`?

Comment: No, I wanted to set my query in my interface public interface DocumentArchiveRepository extends JpaRepository<DocumentArchive, Long> but it seems that I have to create another class and use there JPQL as You mentioned.

Comment: Can you try what you have, with my query, but without `nativeQuery` field?

Comment: @Query  -without nativeQuery = true returns the following error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract (with your query: String QUERY_GET_DOCUMENT_DATA = "SELECT new " + DocumentData.class.getName() + "(d.id_document ... )

Comment: Table1, Table2 are not entities - simply tables in database...Eh still doesn't work. I've tried many approaches but unfortunately so far without success

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I didn't find proper solution for my case with many JOINs WITHOUT ENTITIES. I have to create all necessary entities, only with needed fields, and then used their names in my query (using Select new MyPOJOClass(...))